# Haskell higher order function with map

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

```
test::Int->(Int-> Char)->Char
test n f =  f(n)

DD::Int->Char
DD a | a==1 = '1'
```

test which is a higher order function currently returning a **char** value , i required to return a `String` as  `test::Int->(Int-> Char)->String`

i changed to function body as

```
test::Int->(Int-> Char)->String
test n f =  map f(n)
```

**Error**

```
Type error in application
*** Expression     : map f n
*** Term           : n
*** Type           : Int
*** Does not match : [a]
```

How can i apply this function to a string with map ? where i went wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a string is simply a list of chars, try out to return a list of chars:

```
test n f =  [f n]
```

BTW, in Haskell we usually don't use paranthesis if they are not really needed.